# My card background color exceeds the screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image]

The background color set at the top of my third card and the bottom of my ninth card in the preview screen exceeds the border of the card（I am listening the CS193P）

here is my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    
    let cardShape: CardViewShape
    let color: Color
    let elementsNum: Int
    let fillingMethod: FillingMethod
    
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
                Spacer()
                ForEach(1..<elementsNum+1, id:\.self) {index in
                    cardView(for: cardShape, in: geometry)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            .border(Color.orange, width: 5)
            .background(Color.green)
        }
        .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    private func cardView(for cardShape: CardViewShape, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        switch (cardShape) {
        case .circle:
            let width = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height/CGFloat(elementsNum)) - 10
            Circle()
                .fill(mode: fillingMethod, color: color)
                .frame(maxWidth: width)
        case .rectangle:
            let width = geometry.size.width * 0.65
            let height = geometry.size.height / 5
            Rectangle()
                .fill(mode: fillingMethod, color: color)
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
        case .diamond:
            Diamond()
                .fill(mode: fillingMethod, color: color)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.clipped()` just after your `.background(Color.green)`, such as:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 5) {
            Spacer()
            ForEach(1..<elementsNum+1, id:\.self) {index in
                cardView(for: cardShape, in: geometry)
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        .border(Color.orange, width: 5)
        .background(Color.green)
        .clipped()  // <--- here
    }
    .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.clipped()` in your `private func cardView` for each shape...

```
@ViewBuilder
private func cardView(for cardShape: CardViewShape, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    switch (cardShape) {
    case .circle:
        let width = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height/CGFloat(elementsNum)) - 10
        Circle()
            .fill(mode: fillingMethod, color: color)
            .frame(maxWidth: width)
    case .rectangle:
        let width = geometry.size.width * 0.65
        let height = geometry.size.height / 5
        Rectangle()
            .fill(mode: fillingMethod, color: color)
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .clipped()                                 <--- add here
    case .diamond:
        Diamond()
            .fill(mode: fillingMethod, color: color)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the cards top and bottom are in contact with the safe areas at the top and bottom of the display. When you apply a background color using round parentheses like this:

```swift
.background(Color.green)
```

...then it ignores safe areas by default - see [background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)). This is why the colors are bleeding into the safe areas.

**To fix:**

- either, you can supply an empty set as the parameter `ignoresSafeAreaEdges`:

```swift
.background(Color.green, ignoresSafeAreaEdges: [])
```

- or, you can simply use the background modifier that takes a `ViewBuilder` as parameter, which is usually supplied as a trailing closure (with curly braces):

```
.background { Color.green }
```